# Hightlight specfic digits within siunix's \num

Tags: spacing, siunitx

I would like to highlight specific digits in a number. Since the number is large I would like to use `\num{}` from [the `siunitx` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx).

Of course I can do it manually as in the MWE below, but was hoping that there might be an easy way to use the commented out syntax to accomplish this:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand*{\Color}[2][red]{\textcolor{#1}{#2}}%

\begin{document}

\num{99 976}

88\,9\Color{76} %\num{88 9\Color{76}}

77\,\Color{976} %\num{77 \Color{976}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want something like `\Color{red}{3}{77976}` to be equal to `77\,\Color{976}`?

Comment: @Manuel: I guess that would slightly be better than my solution, but I'd rather use the `\num{}` macro as that provides other options that I may want to use in the future.   Also, that syntax would restrict the highlighting to the right most digits, which is my current issue. But may want to highlight other digits in between as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example defined `\phnum`, which supports `\X` as additional digit. The macro is defined to be a phantom digit, leaving place for a digit.
Then the colored number can be composed by overlaying the number with different colors. The digits of different colors are masked out by `\X`,
for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand*{\phnum}[2][]{%
  \begingroup
    \protected\def\X{\phantom{0}}%
    \num[
      input-digits=0123456789\X,%
      #1%
    ]{#2}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\num{99 976}

\leavevmode
\rlap{\phnum{889\X\X}}\textcolor{red}{\phnum{\X\X\X76}}

\leavevmode
\rlap{\phnum{77\X\X\X}}\textcolor{red}{\phnum{\X\X976}}

\leavevmode
\rlap{\color    {red}\phnum{1\X\X\X\X\X\X}}%
\rlap{\color  {green}\phnum{\X2\X\X\X\X\X}}%
\rlap{\color   {blue}\phnum{\X\X3\X\X\X\X}}%
\rlap{\color   {cyan}\phnum{\X\X\X4\X\X\X}}%
\rlap{\color{magenta}\phnum{\X\X\X\X5\X\X}}%
\rlap{\color {yellow}\phnum{\X\X\X\X\X6\X}}%
                     \phnum{\X\X\X\X\X\X7}    

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Of course, this syntax is quite cumbersome. But at least, the example provides an idea for combining coloring parts of a number and using `\num` at the same time.