# Color a subset of digits in SIUNITX

Tags: beamer, color, siunitx

I am writing a presentation with Beamer, where I show the benchmarks of a program I wrote. This involve comparing a lot of number coming from different sources. These numbers can differ only in the last two or three decimal digits. What I would like to do, is to color only the digits that differes from one numbe to another. The problem is that these numbers are normally contained in a command `\num` or `\SI` of the `siunitx` package.

Is there any way of coloring only the last decimal digits of a number contained in the commands `\num` or `\SI`?

Comment: There is also another question on highlighting certain digits: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163106 If this is not your only concern but also the differing digits from different sources, you will have to add an MWE here.